# Move Ektron assets to a different drive

Tags: content-management-system, ektron

We are running low on disk space on our main drive and we want to move our assets folders to a new drive on the same system.  From what I have seen, it may be as simple as moving the files and editing the AssetManagement.config file with the new locations.

Can anyone confirm this is correct?  I have checked the Ektron developers forum and the Ektron documentation and still don't have a definitive answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to edit the config file. You can change that in Workarea/ settings/ configuration / Document Management / storage location.

Then you can move the C:\AssetFiles\ folder to D:\AssetFiles

To test it, just edit an DMS document in the workarea. It will give you an error or broken link if it can't find the file or folder.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try to test this out this week.